# Internal error (500) on local & Fatal error on live when trying to access post type edit screen

Tags: mysql

I'm building a CMS for a company that has 60,000+ static pages which have been converted into posts. 30,000 of these are a particular post type. When I try to access the edit screen in the admin area (http://www.mysite.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=post-type.

On my local server I get an internal 500 error.

On my live site, (database migrated with wp-migrate-db-pro) i get:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in /home/omol/public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 1876

seems like 256m should be enough memory? I wasn't having this error before and was able to see the 30,000 articles on the edit screen just yesterday.

I've reverted to twenty-twelve theme & checked the htaccess, to no avail.

Comment: Is the "particular post type" hierarchical?

Comment: yes it was! Thank you! I was experimenting with this the other day (and even read about the dangers of doing so!) I appreciate the help! Put this as an answer and I'll give you credit for answering =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you have a hierarchical post type. You will have trouble with hierarchical post types with large numbers of posts because query results have to be  sorted/resorted. Register you post type with hierarchical set to false, if you can.